# Find first date that contains a specific year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to build a MATCH formula (or a similar one) that returns the position of the first value (date) within a range that matches a specific year.

For example, if I have a list of dates, like this:

```
      A
1 12-31-2014
2 11-30-2015
3 12-29-2016
4 12-30-2017
```

For the value 2016, it should return 3.

`MATCH(2016,A:A,0)` doesn't work, since it's not an exact match. I can't use any aux columns either nor modify the dates.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are these actual dates or a string that looks like a date?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad They are formatted as dates.

Comment: @N.Pavon strings will not change their appearance based on formatting.  Change the formatting to general, do the dates change to a 5 digit number?  That would indicate they are dates,  Either way one of the two formulas given below will work.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, they do change to a 5 digit number.

Comment: Then Jeeped's first answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to use array formulas? If so, it may be as simple as this:

`=IFERROR(MATCH(2016,YEAR($A$1:$A$4),0),"No Match")`

Remember to commit the answer using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, since it'll be an array.

You'll want to change the references within the `YEAR` function to match your range. By using **0** as your `[match_type]` parameter, you're going to get the first value in the list that has a year of **2016**.

Answer (score 0):

For real dates, try,

```
=aggregate(15, 6, row($1:$999)/(year(a$1:a$999)=2016), 1)
'return the date with index as,
=index(a:a, aggregate(15, 6, row($1:$999)/(year(a$1:a$999)=2016), 1))
```

If they are in ascending order you could use,

```
=MATCH(42369, A:A)+1
=index(a:a, MATCH(42369, A:A)+1)
```

For a list of strings that look like dates try,

```
=MATCH("*2016", A:A, 0)
=index(a:a, MATCH("*2016", A:A, 0))
```

Comment: Hi, the first formula doesn't work, it doesn't return the right value.

Comment: Actually, they are in ascending order, but is there a way to use that same formula, but without the date "code"? Using only the year.

Comment: That 'date code' is the 'serial date' for 31-Dec-2015. If you put in date(2015, 12, 31) or datevalue("12/31/2015") or anything else that accurately represents 12-31-2015 then you will be fine.